# CollapsingToolbar Title start margin also in collapsed state

Tags: java, android

I'm using a 150dp title margin on expanded state of my CollapsingToolbar to avoid collision with other UI elements.
When the toolbar is collapsed the title ignores that margin, overriding my buttons.
I need a way to maintain the margin also in collapsed state. 
Here my xml:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbarlayoutGBook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMargin="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/collapsingtoolbarGoogleBookTitleMarginStart"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"
            app:title="Book Title">
```

Comment: Try to use app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="150dp" in the toolbar

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Many thanks but it's not working.

Comment: Meanwhile I switched to right gravity. For standard lenght titles it's a good workaround. Unfortunately too long titles overrides anyway my layout.